# What is the difference between returning a function and using function.innerFunction?

Tags: javascript, function, return

Its a general question about something i seem to encounter a lot:
When should i use

```
function Bla(){return function(){alert("bla");}}
```

and call the main function `Bla`,
and when should I use

```
function Bla(){function innerBla(){alert("bla");}}
```

and call `Bla.innerBla`?

What is the difference between them?

Comment: You cannot call Bla.innerBla... Are you talking about creating an instance of Bla with the new keyword, and using `this` to set a property on it? like, `function Bla(){this.innerBla = function(){alert("hello");};}`? And then doing `var x = new Bla(); x.innerBla();`

Comment: Or do you just mean, when should you name your functions?

Comment: @david, Yes this was the genera direction, and your code raises a new question - why cant I use just Bla.innerBla, but to create a new Bla, and only with the new Bla i can gain access to it?

Comment: In my answer, I think I gave you enough examples from what you can choose from.

Comment: @Andreas Grech, thanx you definitely did :) but i still want to understand the theory behind the working of those examples, and in this case why I can gain access only to an instance of a function and not to the function itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Those are two different ways of doing things, and they operate differently.**

The first one is a function that returns another function.  Thus, to invoke the inner function, you need to first call the outer one, `Bla`, (which returns the inner one) and then invoke the returned value (the inner function):

```
function Bla(){
    return function(){
      alert("bla");
    }
}

Bla()(); // will alert "bla"
```

---

The second one just defines an inner function, and there's no way of invoking that inner function from outside of the outer function because it's scoped only within the outer function `Bla`:

```
function Bla(){
    function innerBla () {
      alert("bla");
    }
}

Bla(); // will do 'nothing'
```

`Bla.innerBla` is `undefined` because the object (functions are objects in JavaScript) `Bla` does not have a member called `innerBla` attached to it.

---

If you want to invoke it like `bla.innerBla`, you should do something like this:

```
function bla () { /* */ }

bla.innerBla = function () {
    alert("bla");
};

bla.innerBla(); 
// will alert "bla" because the `bla` object now has a member called `innerBla`.
```

Or you can have something like this (a pattern that I frequently use):

```
function bla () {
    return {
        innerBla: function () {
            alert("bla");
        }
    };
}

bla().innerBla(); // will also alert "bla"
```

---

If you want to use the constructor pattern (`new`), you need to do something like this:

```
var bla = function () {
  this.innerBla = function () {
    alert("bla");
  };
};

var b = new bla();
b.innerBla();
```

This is equivalent to having a public property on an instance of an object in an OO language.

---

And finally, if you want to expose `innerBla` by every 'instance' (achieved using a constructor i.e. invoking `bla` using the `new` keyword) of `bla`, you should add the function  to `bar.prototype.innerBla`:

```
var bla = function () { /* */ };
bla.prototype.innerBla = function () {
  alert("bla");
};

var b1 = new bla(), 
    b2 = new bla();

b1.innerBla(); // will alert "bla"
b2.innerBla(); // will also alert "bla"
```

This is similar to having a static method.

---

*On a side note, avoid naming functions with an initial capital case letter (pascal-case) because by convention, usually we only capitalize functions which need to be invoked using the `new` keyword (constructors).*

Comment: In the second example, did you mean to have `this.innerBla = ...` inside of the function?

Comment: oh stupid question I didn't read correctly your code... Deleted it, anyway your answer has been a huge help